# Do I need to use JSON.stringify to save an object in localstorage in JS?

Tags: javascript

I was watching a Youtube video and I see that we don't have to use `JSON.stringify` everytime to save in LocalStorage. For example, on line 11 of JS in Codepen, we dont use `JSON.stringify` when setting name item in LocalStorage. but in line 26, we use JSON.stringify when setting item in LocalStorage? Is there a difference? Here is the code pen link.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/minsolaroo/pen/oNyPrPY)

Comment: One is an object, one is a plain string. Local storage can only store strings

Comment: Agree. stringify before you set, parse after you get.

Comment: If you look at the standard you'll see that the value must be a string: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-storage-setitem-dev

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have provided, two types of values used in the specified two instances are different.

In line 10,

```
nameInput.addEventListener('change' , e => {
    localStorage.setItem('username', e.target.value)
})
```

Here, the `e.target.value` will give out a single value of type string. Because the nameInput is a text input. Therefore, there's no need to use `JSON.stringify` in this segment.

In line 26,

```
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
```

`todos` is initialized as an array of values in line 2.

```
todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || []
```

In JavaScript to store array values in local storage, it should be converted to JSON string. Since `JSON.stringify` is used here.

[Check this article](https://melvingeorge.me/blog/save-arrays-objects-to-localstorage-javascript) on how to store and retrieve JavaScript arrays in local storage.